# How to eliminate use of external browser when querying Spotify API

Tags: java, android, spotify

I am using java in Android Studio and my token retrieval works as intended, I am just being picky about the momentary appearance of an external browser that is retrieving the token. Is there a way to eliminate/hide that momentary switch so the user's flow is not interrupted?

I know it is possible through a webView but I really am just asking for guidance on how to implement that in my program.

Comment: You can get the token by [client credential](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/client-credentials-flow) method without user login but it can't get the user's resources like a private playlist, or add song, delete songs, get current play song and so on.